# How to get data by applying condition on relational field using Laravel eloquent relation from MongoDB?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am working in Laravel 5.7 with MongoDB 4.0

Defined relation in Post Model as follow:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne(Users::class,'_id','user_id');
}
```

trying to get data using query:

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->whereHas('user',function($q){
    $q->where('first_name', 'Test User');
});
```

There are some posts uploaded by given user,but I found nothing.
How can I get posts uploaded by given user using Laravel eloquent Relations?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Or database structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse your query and retrieve all posts related with the user.

```
//In User.php Model
use App\Post;

public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post:class);
}
```

For retrieving the data:

```
// Retrieving the data
public function getRelatedPosts(){
    $user = User::where('first_name', 'Jignasa')->first();
    $posts = null;
    if(!empty($user)){
        $posts = $user->posts;
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

Comment: My bad!! I asked in a wrong way. Actually I am listing all the posts and want to filter that posts by the user's name who uploaded the post.

Comment: Do you have created_by which stores the id of the user who created the post?

Comment: There is a field 'user_id' in 'posts' collection to store created by user's id.

Comment: Try using ->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id') in Post model

Comment: You forget to ->get() all the posts.